# Page will not load until any file is saved or server is restarted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create a new page I can see it is saved in console and in database.
However, when I try to view the page I get the error

```
No route matches [GET] "/page-slug"
```

this is my route file, I believe the area to focus on is the Page.where.not...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

resources :publicpages, only: [:show]
resources :categories, only: [:show]
resources :menus, only: [:show] 

namespace :admin do
    get '/dashboard', to: 'admin#dashboard'
    resources :menus, except: [:show]
    resources :pages
    resources :categories
end

 Page.where.not("slug" => nil).all.each do |page|
     get "/#{page.slug}", controller: "pages", action: "show", id: page.id
 end
end
```

The routing works as soon as I save any file or restart the server.  Until I do one of those two things the page will continue to throw that error though.  Kind of baffled on how to solve this issue so that I can view the page right away without having to save a file or restart server, I have never encountered this before, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that your `routes.rb` is only getting reloaded on file save or server restart. Creating a new page does not cause `routes.rb` to reload and, therefore, the route for the new page is not defined.

Here's a [post](http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4) on how to accomplish what you're trying. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reload the routes just like @jvillian pointed out.

The above comment pointed me in the right direction with the link to the blog post.  I am going to post this answer only so I can show that actual code I needed to create to solve the problem.

created dynamic_route.rb
models/dynamic_router.rb

```
class DynamicRouter
  def self.load
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    Page.all.each do |pg|
      puts "Routing #{pg.slug}"
      get "/#{pg.slug}", :to => "pages#show", defaults: { id: pg.id }
    end
  end
end

 def self.reload
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

In config/routes.rb

```
DynamicRouter.load
```

in the the page model, models/page.rb

```
after_save :reload_routes

def reload_routes
  DynamicRouter.reload
end
```

With that I can redirect to the page on save and it is ready to go, exactly what I needed.  Thanks @jvillian for the link.